# Anime featuring a circus

Tags: kaleido-star

I remember an anime about a girl from Japan who came to the United States (where everyone speaks Japanese, apparently) to join a famous high-tech sort of circus.

What I can't remember is the name of that anime. Could anyone give me a lead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the limited information provided, my best guess is that you are looking for [Kaleido Star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaleido_Star):

> Sora Naegino, a **young Japanese girl** with a great talent for acrobatics, comes to the **United States** in hopes of auditioning for the Kaleido Stage, a world famous **circus** which has mesmerized her since childhood.